# reading File with FileStream

Tags: c#, filestream

Hi im using,

```
  FileStream file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

to read files from my Temp-Folder that i defined in Debug-Directory but with no Success.
with this code i can read Files just from Debug-Folder.
can anyone help!

this is my Code

```
private void button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string activeDirectory = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\Temp\\";

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(activeDirectory);
        try
        {
            foreach (string fileName in files.Select(f => f.Substring(activeDirectory.Length)))
            {
                FileStream file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            }
        }
        catch()
        {}
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong/ What problem are you having?

Comment: To be able to help you, we need to see how you obtain the fileName variable.

Comment: Don't swallow the exceptions. They might contain useful information about the problem.

Comment: i would like to have access to the Temp Folder

Comment: i want to have just filename example fileName.txt That means 'Skip x chars and return the rest

Comment: probably because its a debug build.Did you tried with the release build

Comment: but my exe data excit in debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running the debug build then 
`System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath` will return you the path of the debug folder,since your exe is present in that folder.